# How to put text next to each other

Tags: html

how do I put text side by side? I'd like to have numbers side by side and with minimal inbetween them spaces but everything I do doesn't seem to work.

```html
  <p><a href='index.html'><center>1</center></a></p>
        <p><a href='page2.html'><center>2</center></a></p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: show us what css you tried before asking SO

Answer (score 0):

The following will literally put the numbers side-by-side, but I'm not sure this is really what you want. You can put a normal space between `</a>` and `<a...`.

```html
  <p><a href='index.html'>1</a><a href='page2.html'>2</a></p>
```

EDIT: Also please note that this depends on your CSS style definitions.

Comment: I want them next to each other as in; 1 2. What do I add to the CSS style is what I'm trying to say, cause right now I'm having no luck.

Comment: @Zapper, just put aspace between `</a>` and `<a...`

Comment: @Zapper, if you want more help you'll need to provide us access to the page you're building. You could post it in a codepen or jsfiddle, and provide us a link. It'll be a simple matter at that point.